# Clojure: minimal number implementation that supports meta?

Tags: clojure

I'd like to implement some basic Physics/Chemistry formulas in Clojure.
I want to emphasize not on performance but on convenience, so the main
feature is type-checking. I was thinking that attaching meta to numbers
would accomplish the task.

For instance, this function:

```
(defn force [mass accel]
  (* mass accel))
```

Should

1. Access the meta of first argument
2. Make sure it's of mass type, i.e. kilograms, grams etc. Throw an error if it's not.
3. Convert the numeric value to kilograms.
4. Do the same for acceleration.
5. Return the result with meta of Newtons.

I can overload `*` and other functions appropriately in my namespace.

The only problem is that it's impossible to attach meta to a `Double`.
What's a good way to get a something that behaves like a number, but can have metadata?

Comment: Since `java.lang.Long` and friends are `final`, is using `java.math.BigDecimal` an option? If so you could extend it and implement `clojure.lang.IObj`.

Comment: Which way should I extend? deftype/gen-class/reify? Can you give me a small example?

Comment: I just added an answer with some code. I was curious about how you would go about implementing it so it's really not that small an example :P. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach using `gen-class`. I just mocked the functions for checking and normalizing units. The only operation implemented is `*` which is used in `force`.

Please note that since the code is using `gen-class` and `compile` you'll need to save the following code to a file named `big_decimal_meta.clj` in the `src` folder of your leiningen project folder and then load it.

`BigDecimalMeta` using `gen-class`:

```cljs
(ns big-decimal-meta
  (:refer-clojure :exclude [* force])
  (:gen-class
    :name        BigDecimalMeta
    :extends     java.math.BigDecimal
    :state       metadata
    :init        init
    :implements  [clojure.lang.IObj]))

(defn -init [& args]
  [args (atom nil)])

(defn -withMeta [this metadata]
  (reset! (.metadata this) metadata)
  this)

(defn -meta [this]
  (deref (.metadata this)))

(compile 'big-decimal-meta)
```

`*` and `force` functions with some example code:

```cljs
(def x (with-meta (BigDecimalMeta. 1) {:unit :kg}))
(def y (with-meta (BigDecimalMeta. 3.5) {:unit :mss}))
(def z (with-meta (BigDecimalMeta. 4.5) {:unit :V}))

(defn unit [x]
  (-> x meta :unit))

(defn * [x y]
  (BigDecimalMeta. (str (.multiply x y))))

(defn mass? [x]
  (#{:kg :gr :mg ,,,} (unit x)))

(defn accel? [x]
  (#{:mss ,,,} (unit x)))

(defn to-kg [x] x)
(defn to-mss [x] x)

(defn force [mass accel]
  (assert (mass? mass))
  (assert (accel? accel))
  (let [mass   (to-kg  mass)
        accel  (to-mss accel)]
    (with-meta (* mass accel) {:unit :N})))

(println (force x y) (meta (force x y))) 
(println (force x z) (meta (force x z)))
```

Answer (score 2):

All this is much easier if you just create maps that contain both a number and a unit, rather than trying to smuggle the unit in as part of the number's metadata. After all, the unit is not conceptually bookkeeping data about the number: it is an integral part of the computation you are performing. And it's not as if you can ever use the number while ignoring its unit, so the ability to pass a decorated number into some "dumb" unit-unaware function such as `+` is not interesting either.

Given all this, it's easy to implement your `force` example function:

```
(defn force [{munit :unit :as mass} {aunit :unit :as accel}]
  (assert (mass? munit))
  (assert (accel? aunit))
  {:unit :newton, :magnitude (* (:magnitude (to-kg mass)) 
                                (:magnitude (to-mss accel)))})
```

And of course if your `to-kg` and `to-mss` functions check the types themselves, you can omit them in `force`. Don't give up on the simplicity and transparency of maps for the imagined convenience of having numbers with metadata on them.

Comment: Two times force is still force. Having decorated numbers means that I can use them in
a lot of plain functions. And the point of overloading is to build a DSL that makes adding
unit checking to functions as simple as possible (ideally `(defn force ^:Newton [^:kg mass ^:mss accel] (* mass accel))`).